# Storing Entity Framework Objects in Dictionary

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dictionary

I can't seem to load an "entity" into a dictionary.  I get a "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object"** when trying to add anything to the dictionary.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
private TranslationEntities _db = new TranslationEntities();

private Dictionary<int, Language> _data;


private void LoadData()
        {
             var languages = _db.Languages.Include("Region").OrderBy(e => e.Region.Name).ThenBy(e => e.Name);

             foreach (Language item in languages)
              {
                   _data.Add(item.Id, item);   //// ERRORS HERE ////
              }
        }
```

Comment: just wondering: if you have the entire object, cant you just put it in a list of languages then? you have the entire "item" object, which means you automatically have acces to your "item.id"

Comment: Jane, I could do that but the dictionary will provide fast acceess to a single item, based on its Id...item.Id is the key value for the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize your `dictionary` before invoking any functions on that.

```
private void LoadData()
{
    _data = new Dictionary<int, Language>();
    var languages = _db.Languages.Include("Region").OrderBy(e => e.Region.Name).ThenBy(e => e.Name);

    foreach (Language item in languages)
    {
        _data.Add(item.Id, item);   //// ERRORS HERE ////
    }
}
```

Here i initialized inside the method. You may consider initializing the dictionary in your class `constructor` as well depending on your scenario/code.